# Uniform convergence of the given series of function.

Tags: real-analysis

We need to check the convergence and uniform convergence of $\sum fn(x)$ , where , $fn(x)$ = $(-1)^{n}/(n+x)$ .

I tried the weierstrass M test but it fails here , clearly the series converges by comparing it with an alternating series , but what about its UNIFORM convergence ?

And , for a series of function to converge uniformly to $f$ , the sequence must converge uniformly to $f$ , is it correct ?

Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This series converges **conditionally** for every $x$.  To see this, fix some $x\geq0$.  Then once $n>x$, $\dfrac{1}{n+x}\geq\dfrac{1}{2n}$, so by the comparison test, the series $\displaystyle\sum_n\dfrac{1}{n+x}$ diverges.  Similarly if $x<0$.

Comment: But that's for UNIFORM convergence , right ? You considered the absolute value of the sequence .. am i right ?

Comment: @RohitDuggal, yes, thats right, as you noted in the problem the series itself converges by the AST.  I have edited my answer appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

Try Leibniz theorem for alternating series

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty$ $(-1)^{n}u_{n}$ converges when

i) $lim_{n \to \infty}{u_n} =0$ and

ii){$u_n$} is monotonically decreasing sequence.

Comment: That gives the convergence , but what about UNIFORM convergence ?

Answer (score 1):

The series converges uniformly on $[0,\infty).$ Proof: Let $S_n(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k+x}.$ Then

$$S_{2n}(x) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \left ( \frac{1}{2k + x}-\frac{1}{2k-1 + x}\right ) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} \frac{-1}{(2k + x)(2k-1+x)}.$$

In absolute value, the terms in the last sum are $\le \frac{1}{2k(2k-1)}.$ (We used the fact that $x\ge 0$ here.) By the Weierstrass M test, we see $S_{2n}$ converges to some $f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty).$ Since

$$ |S_{2n+1}(x) - f(x)| \le |S_{2n}(x) - f(x)| +\left |\frac{1}{x+2n+1}\right | \le |S_{2n}(x) - f(x)| + \frac{1}{2n+1},$$

we see $S_{2n+1} \to f$ uniformly on $[0,\infty)$ as well. Therefore the full series converges uniformly to $f$ on $[0,\infty).$

What about the rest of $\mathbb {R}$? There is something to worry about with negative $x$ of course: $\frac{1}{x+n}$ blows up at $-n.$ Still I think the following is true: For any $a<0,$ the series converges uniformly on $[a,0]\setminus \{-1,-2,\cdots \}.$ Try to prove this!